# How to use AngularJS $http to fetch data returned by an ExpressJS endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, promise

I have an ExpressJS route as below:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.get('/someURL', function (req, res) {
    exec('cp file1 file2', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            // node couldn't execute the command
            return;
        }

        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log(stderr);

    });
    return stdout;
  })
```

This is basically to run a CLI command when the user goes to the specified route on the web app.

In my AngularJS controller I have the following function:

```
function getData() {

    let deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someURL'
    }).then((response) => {
      deferred.resolve(response);
    }, (error) => {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}


this.getData().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   }).catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err, err.stack);
   });
```

When I run the application, I am getting the html code as the response at `console.log(response)`, instead of `stdout`. How do I correct that?

Comment: You're not sending a response, just doing some logging.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/someURL', function (req, res) {
    // Here do the processing that you need to do
res.send('response');
  })
```

In your expressJS server, you are intercepting the request but you are not sending anything back. You have to specifically send something back using the 'res' object from the funtion parameter. You can add http status codes too like

```
res.status('200').send(data);
```